# How do I set up a Reactjs live server that can still access the chrome extensions api?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm designing a chrome extension that overrides chrome://newtab so that when you open a new tab, it displays my custom code rather than the normal. I'm using react as my UI library and it makes calls to the chrome.storage API. The only way for me to test it is to run `npm run build` but that takes a lot of time to create every time and debugging is a huge chore.

Is there a way to do `npm run start` do it live updates on localhost while still maintaining functionality or do I have to build it every time? If so, how can I cut down on build time?

Comment: There's usually `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` commands which do a superfast build.